# Is it okay to have two base.html templates in django?

Tags: django, django-models, django-views, django-forms, django-templates

Is it okay to have multiple base.html templates in django? For instance, I would have one template that would extend from base_one.html and another template extending from base_two.html. For example, this is one of the templates:

```
{% extends "base_one.html" %}

{% block content %}
{% endblock content %}
```

and this is another template:

```
{% extends "base_two.html" %}

{% block content %}
{% endblock content %}
```

Comment: Yes, completely okay.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well not only two you can keep how much you want just with different names and you have to extend on different templates but yeah you can easily keep parts of the base template and extend in one according to your needs.

I'm adding three files here 1-base.html 2-base-comments.html 3-post-template.html

Here is a little expansion of my answer
Suppose this file name is **base.html**

```
# base.html
    <html>
        <head>
            <title>Foo</title>
        </head>
        <body>
            <header>
                {% block header %}
                    <h1>Lorem ipsum</h1>
                {% endblock %}
            </header>
            {% block content %}{% comment %}A wrapper around content is needed{% endcomment %}
                <div class="page-content">
                    {% block page_content %}{% comment %} Filled in by your page templates {% endcomment %}
                    {% endblock %}
                </div>
            {% endblock %}
            <footer>
                {% block footer %}
                    <em>&#x2665; joar</em>
                {% endblock footer %}
            </footer>
        </body>
    </html>
```

here is another file **base-comments.html** which extends the previous file.

```
# base-comments.html
    {% extends 'base.html' %}
    {% block content %}
        <div class="page-content">
            {% block page_content %}{% comment %} Filled in by your page templates {% endcomment %}
            {% endblock %}
            
            {% block comments %}
                <footer>
                    <h2>Comments</h2>
                    <script>loadCommentsEtc()</script>
                </footer>
            {% endblock %}
        </div>
    {% endblock %}
```

And here is the last file which extends the 2nd base file which already extends the 1st base file 3-post-template.html

```
# post-template.html
    {% extends 'base-comments.html' %}
    {% block page_content %}
        <article>
            <h1>{{ post.title }}</h1>
            <div class="post-body">
                {{ post.body }}
            </div>
        </article>
    {% endblock %}
```

I hope this works and clears your doubts.
Thanks for the question.